# Robot Framework, How to keep continue the test cases even if any failure

Tags: robotframework

I am new to Robot and am learning to write logic and test cases.

I have a test suite, **monitoring.robot**, which has a lot of test cases. test cases like Homepage web1, home page web2, home page web3...etc. 
If any steps gets failed then execution should not stopped that should keep continue to till end of the transaction?

**monitoring.robot**

```
Test Case## Heading ##
echo Trans01_WebSites-helloPublicWebsite
open    https://www.morganre.com/
assertTitle    abcd  Group | abcd 
echo    Trans02_WebSites-CorporateSolutions
open    https://corporatesolutions.hello.com/
assertTitle    abcd  Corporate Solutions
echo    Trans03_WebSites-OpenMinds
open    https://openminds.hello.com/
assertTitle    abcd  - Open Minds
echo    Trans04_WebSites-Arthello
open    http://art.hello.com/
assertTitle    Art at abcd 
close    win_ser_local
Close All Browsers
```

Execution that should not stop even if any failure occurred in the middle of any test case.

Comment: Have you tried the standard keyword [Run Keyword And Continue On Failure](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Continue%20On%20Failure)?

Answer (score 6):

Robot Framework has useful methods:

1. `Run Keyword And Continue On Failure    open    https://www.morganre.com/`
2. `Run Keyword And Ignore Error    open    https://www.morganre.com/`

Both are ok for you, but the first one will display the failed method with fail status, the second one will ignore the error.

For detailed information please refer to http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html

Comment: Thanks Aleks for your reply. 
however , i am getting error which saying that 'No Keyword with name Run keyword and continue on failure Open'. 

also, i am keeping the keywords library (seleniumkeywords.robot) aside where i have defined the keywords definition. so, how to define the keywords definition for Run keyword and continue on failure Open file. 

Thanks,
Senthil

Comment: Please ensure that you have 2+ spaces between `Run Keyword And Continue On Failure` and `Open` as 2+ spaces are a delimiter in Robot Framework. Your error suggests that there is only 1 space and thus sees the entire string as the keyword name.